# play framework 1.2, pass parameters to running job

Tags: playframework, jobs, playframework-1.x

i have a Job that run on start-up. the job run's on a list of items and do something network operations with each item.

since i have new items to process rapidly. i want the job to run while the application is running, and pass new items to the job when available.

inside the Job i have an inner Object that will

```
waitObject.wait();
```

when all items was processed , and

```
waitObject.notify();
```

when new items available;

my questions are:

1) i don't know how to access the Job that runs on start-up ?

2) is this the correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for something like this it would be better to use a job with @Every("5mn") annotation and read whatever information you need from the database?